# Merge two PDF/A result should be a valid PDF/A too pdfbox

Tags: java, merge, pdfbox, pdfa

I'm using pdfbox to merge two PDF/A

Right now my code look like this:

```
    PDFMergerUtility mergerUtility = new PDFMergerUtility();

    File file = new File("example/c.pdf");

    mergerUtility.addSource(new File("example/a.pdf"));
    mergerUtility.addSource(new File("example/b.pdf"));

    mergerUtility.setDestinationFileName(file.getAbsolutePath());

    try {
        mergerUtility.mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting.setupMainMemoryOnly());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to merge", ex);
    }

    File inputFile = new File("example/c.pdf");
    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(inputFile);

    File orig = new File("example/a.pdf");
    PDDocument origDoc = PDDocument.load(orig);
    File orig2 = new File("example/b.pdf");
    PDDocument orig2Doc = PDDocument.load(orig2);
    PDStructureTreeRoot treeRoot = origDoc.getDocumentCatalog().getStructureTreeRoot();
    PDStructureTreeRoot treeRoot2 = orig2Doc.getDocumentCatalog().getStructureTreeRoot();
    treeRoot.setKids(treeRoot2.getKids());
    doc.getDocumentCatalog().setStructureTreeRoot(treeRoot);

    List<PDOutputIntent> outputIntents=new ArrayList<>();
    outputIntents.add(doc.getDocumentCatalog().getOutputIntents().get(0));
    doc.getDocumentCatalog().setOutputIntents(outputIntents);
    doc.save("example/d.pdf");
    doc.close();
```

by setting OutputIntent the same as the first page (so that d.pdf got only one) I already solved a lot of problems... the last problem that I got (only on this validator https://avepdf.com/pdfa-validation ) was 4:

"Non-standard structure type is not mapped to any functionally equivalent standard type."

I was able to identify them and they are due to the use of "THead" and "TBody" on my result (generated by pdfbox).

I was able to cut that error in half (now I only got 2 "Non-standard structure type is not mapped to any functionally equivalent standard type.") by using the same StructureTreeRoot as one of the original file (that's the "final" code that you can see, still not able to get a valid PDF/A from a merge of two PDF/A)... but I don't know how to merge those two StructureTreeRoot or if that's even the real solution (maybe there is a way to tell pdfbox just to avoid using THead and TBody instead).

The result is already good as it pass most pdf/a validator out there, I just need that it pass also that validator (since it is the one used by the company I work for)... Also I don't think the validator is to blame since both input files pass as valid PDF/A file.

Got any ideas?

PS. I found a way to merge the two PDStructureTreeRoot still not working... but I updated the code. adding

```
PDStructureTreeRoot treeRoot2 = orig2Doc.getDocumentCatalog().getStructureTreeRoot();
treeRoot.setKids(treeRoot2.getKids());
```

Comment: What PDFBox version are you using? PDFBox does some work trying to merge the two structure trees, what you do is to keep only one so you're losing the accessibility. It would be interesting to get the two source PDFs.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot share those files... I'm using pdfbox version 2.0.28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... this was really tough.
For the first time I had to get help from an chatgpt, but it was still not enough because of course the AI was not able to create large amount of working code, each time I had to make corrections, it was still a good help to translate what I had in mind with code samples (a kind of protocode).
Anyway the most important thing that I had to understand is that it was not possible to solve my problem by cloning the StructureTreeRoot (but that's in my edit) so I deleted that part of my code, no reason to keep it.
I did not understand how to avoid the creation of THead or TBody.
So the only thing that I could do was to replace every single one of them with a standard alternative like P.

The first problem was how to get the root in a way that I could iterate on it. To understand that I started by debugging my tree and access it manually until I reached a THead... I had some direction thanks to the structure that I could read with Visual Studio Code inside of the generated PDF. The AI was a little help here to understand how to access some variables that were protected and that I could only access in debug mode.

```
COSDictionary catalogDict = doc2.getDocumentCatalog().getCOSObject();
COSObject structTreeRootRef = (COSObject) catalogDict.getItem(COSName.STRUCT_TREE_ROOT);
COSDictionary structTreeRootDict = (COSDictionary) structTreeRootRef.getObject();
COSBase result = structTreeRootDict.getItem(COSName.K);
COSDictionary dict1 = result instanceof COSObject ? (COSDictionary) ((COSObject) result).getObject() : null;
//this
COSArray array = result instanceof COSArray ? (COSArray) result : new COSArray();
//or
COSBase result1 = dict1.getItem(COSName.K);
COSArray array = result1 instanceof COSArray ? (COSArray) result1 : new COSArray();
```

I don't have the original code but basically after this first part I just did a get(i) because I knew each node that I needed to get and finally

```
subDict.setItem(COSName.S, COSName.getPDFName("P"));
```

Of course that was already working code (and that was great since to get to that point I had to learn how to access the pdf tree and pdfbox is not intuitive on that end at all) but of course I was not done because my solution was working only for two pdf/a of my own example. So I decided to turn the get(i) in for loops. Better but still not a great solution because when I tried another pdf where my THead and TBody where one layer deeper I had to add another for loop inside to make it working again... and of course the performance were not great.
That's where chatgpt helped again by presenting a recursive alternative (the solution was trivial but honestly said it hadn't occurred to me at all)... I still had to correct the code a lot but in the end the correct solution was this:

```
    COSDictionary catalogDict = doc2.getDocumentCatalog().getCOSObject();
    COSObject structTreeRootRef = (COSObject) catalogDict.getItem(COSName.STRUCT_TREE_ROOT);
    COSDictionary structTreeRootDict = (COSDictionary) structTreeRootRef.getObject();
    COSName newName = COSName.getPDFName("P");

    updateStructureTree(structTreeRootDict, newName);
```

recursive Method:

```
private static void updateStructureTree(COSDictionary dict, COSName newName) {
    COSBase result = dict.getItem(COSName.K);
    COSDictionary dict1 = result instanceof COSObject ? (COSDictionary) ((COSObject) result).getObject() : null;

    if(dict1 != null){
        COSBase result1 = dict1.getItem(COSName.K);
        COSArray array = result1 instanceof COSArray ? (COSArray) result1 : new COSArray();

        for (COSBase resultItem : array) {
            COSDictionary subDict = resultItem instanceof COSObject ?
                    (COSDictionary) ((COSObject) resultItem).getObject() :
                    new COSDictionary();

            if (subDict.getItem(COSName.S) != null &&
                    (subDict.getItem(COSName.S).equals(COSName.getPDFName("THead")) ||
                            subDict.getItem(COSName.S).equals(COSName.getPDFName("TBody")))) {
                subDict.setItem(COSName.S, newName);
            }

            updateStructureTree(subDict, newName);
        }
    }else{
        COSArray array = result instanceof COSArray ? (COSArray) result : new COSArray();

        for (COSBase resultItem : array) {
            COSDictionary subDict = resultItem instanceof COSObject ?
                    (COSDictionary) ((COSObject) resultItem).getObject() :
                    new COSDictionary();

            if (subDict.getItem(COSName.S) != null &&
                    (subDict.getItem(COSName.S).equals(COSName.getPDFName("THead")) ||
                            subDict.getItem(COSName.S).equals(COSName.getPDFName("TBody")))) {
                subDict.setItem(COSName.S, newName);
            }

            updateStructureTree(subDict, newName);
        }
    }
}
```

PS I found an alternative:
just create a List and

```
mergerUtility.setDocumentMergeMode(PDFMergerUtility.DocumentMergeMode.OPTIMIZE_RESOURCES_MODE);
for (int i = 1; i < lists.size(); i++) {
    PDDocument currentDoc = PDDocument.load(lists.get(i));

    mergerUtility.appendDocument(docC, currentDoc);
}
```

and save your new docs... Using appendDocument instead of mergeDocuments will not invalidate a PDF/A even if it got THead and TBody... and it will also not change the header version.

Comment: I'm skeptical of all this. THead and TBody are valid names. You should use Acrobat Professional or PDF-XCHange to see where these structures point to. Just replacing them with P means you're losing some accessibility.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I can assure you that this validator https://avepdf.com/pdfa-validation that I need to use will complain about "Non-standard structure type is not mapped to any functionally equivalent standard type." and will point to THead and TBody and when I replace them the validator will not complain. I'm not sure why, but I could not find another solution.

Comment: also for me it would be so much easier if it would not complain about that... after all everything else was working... I had to make this question for this reason and nobody tried to answer it, so I had to create an answer myself. you can disagree, but this is my own solution to my own question.

Comment: @Tilman is right to mention that **THead** and **TBody** are standard structure types. But they are so with the requirement "Internal to a **Table** structure", so maybe in the former merge result some **THead** and **TBody** tags ended up outside of a **Table** which the validator communicated in a somewhat misleading manner. But this is pure guesswork. To really help we'd need a way to reproduce the issue, including example PDFs.

Comment: @mkl I cannot provide an example since the pdf that I use it's not mine. Also I don't know how to create a new example with the same structure but without that informations. Still I used PDF-XChange like Tilman suggested and the THead and TBody are used inside a Table tag. I tried a lot today but I will need to focus on another project from monday so I think I will stay with my solution... For everyone else is still a good way to know how to replace a tag in any pdf with pdfbox, still not something I found in any other stackoverflow answer.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I found an alternative (and better) solution. Just avoid using mergeDocuments and use appendDocument instead. That's what solved my problem without the need to replace THead/TBody. Still not sure why the mergeDocuments result is wrong, but the appendDocument got THead and TBody and still pass the validator. I'll still keep both answer here so that if someone need to replace some tag for any other reason there is a solution for that too.

Comment: @mkl I found an alternative (and better) solution. Just avoid using mergeDocuments and use appendDocument instead. That's what solved my problem without the need to replace THead/TBody. Still not sure why the mergeDocuments result is wrong, but the appendDocument got THead and TBody and still pass the validator. I'll still keep both answer here so that if someone need to replace some tag for any other reason there is a solution for that too.

Comment: Great! It's a pity, though, that you cannot share the pdfs. Tilman surely would like to fix the merger utility.

Comment: `mergeDocuments()` calls `appendDocument()` when using legacy mode which is the default.